# Tomcat : Where to configure jmx JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I have Tomcat installed on ubuntu. I want to enable JMX for monitoring so in catalina.sh I modified `JAVA_OPTS` as:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"`

After restarting JMX is working but when I want to stop tomcat It gives error as:

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException
>   : Port already in use: 5555;nested exception is:
>       java.net.BindException: Address already in use:

After some Google search I come to know that we have write all JMX configurations to `CATALINA_OPTS` but after writing all configurations inside CATALINA_OPTS I am not able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file alongside `catalina.sh` called `setenv.sh`. That way all your changes are in a separate file.

Use `CATALINA_OPTS` rather than `JAVA_OPTS` since `CATALINA_OPTS` is only used on start whereas `JAVA_OPTS` is used on start and stop.

Comment: Hey, How setenv.sh file get called? I mean where its written/configured to execute setenv.sh or we have write some for the same. Coz I have created the file as you said but nothing happens.

Comment: It is called from catalina.sh

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Tomcat from packages, you have to modify JAVA_OPTS in the file

```
/etc/default/tomcat...
```

Comment: But if I modify JAVA_OPTS then while stopping tomcat service I got error like  java.rmi.server.ExportException : Port already in use:

Comment: CATALINA_OPTS, not JAVA_OPTS

Comment: Yeas use the /etc/default/tomcat file and use CATALINA_OPTS.

Comment: CATALINA_OPTS is for startup only but JAVA_OPTS is used for start AND stop

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything running on port 5555? You can try running

```
lsof -i :5555 or netstat -tulpn | grep :\5555
```

to see what's running on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to make the answer further clear, I am adding the below.

I created a file `setenv.sh` under `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/`. The file content is as below.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
                   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.40.10"
```

There is no need of adding the file setenv.sh in catalina.sh since by seeing the file in name of setenv.sh tomcat will accept the parameters automatically.
Then I added a line in bold font as below in `catalina.sh`.

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi
***export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090"***
```

This way we can avoid port conflict issue in Tomcat. Thanks.